# Can't set PHP cookie on the same page

Tags: php, cookies

I'm having trouble setting cookies on the same page. I used cookies on my site and it works fine, I tend to set make the php in separate file. Now, I'm setting a cookie on the same page but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$expire = time()+5;
setcookie("rb_vote", 1, $expire);
```

then check if it is set

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["rb_vote"]))  {
echo "IS SET";}
else {
echo "IS NOT SET"; }
```

It always says is not set. I tried doing this in page load but still doesn't work.

Comment: As @Pekka said: Cookies are sent from the browser on a page request. So they only appear in $_COOKIE on the next request after setcookie().

Answer (score 11):

See the [manual on setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) (emphasis mine):

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed **on the next page load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also exist in $_REQUEST

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#98096) is a workaround suggestion. It's imperfect because it can't guarantee the cookie actually gets set, but might do in your case.

Comment: It looks like the comment you linked to in the PHP manual no longer exists.

Comment: @Jason and all http://www.lmpx.com/nav/article.php/news.php.net/php.notes/169603/read/index.html

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#98096 that anchor doesn't seem to exist for that workaround link you posted. I even checked the HTML source; nada.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner and all http://web.archive.org/web/20120502174621/http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#98096

Answer (score 5):

I've just encountered this issue in Vanilla Forum. On the first page load, before a session has been established, a session cookie is created, but then every time the application wants to access the session variables (to add to them) it looks for the current session ID in $_COOKIE, which is not set until the next page load.

My workaround is to set the $_COOKIE element manually when the cookie is created.

```
// Create a cookie to identify the session.
// This line already exists. $Name is the cookie name.
// $SessionID is a random md5 ID that has just been generated.
setcookie($Name, $SessionID, $Expire, $Path, $Domain);

// Set the cookie for the remainder of the page. This is a workaround.
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$Name])) $_COOKIE[$Name] = $SessionID;
```

I've raised this as a fault with Vanilla (https://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden/issues/1568), as this workaround feels like a bit of a hack, but it certainly gets around the problem for now.

PHP5.3 Vanilla Forum Version 2.0.18.4

Comment: This is genius, as it totally got me around that "cookie can't be ready on the page it's set" issue. Nice work!