# PHP - setcookie doesn't take effect

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
    setcookie("name", "abc");
    echo $_COOKIE["name"];
?>
```

When I reload this page, it shows nothing on the screen. Why?

But reload again, abc is shown.

WHY??

Comment: So does this show up first on the second time you load the page or the third time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't set PHP cookie on the same page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455214/cant-set-php-cookie-on-the-same-page)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you set a cookie, it is not available until the next page load.

This is very clearly laid out in [the documentation](http://php.net/setcookie), which you should read.

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on **the next page load** with the $_COOKIE or $HTTP_COOKIE_VARS arrays. Note, superglobals such as $_COOKIE became available in PHP 4.1.0. Cookie values also exist in $_REQUEST.

and

> Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for. To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expire parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);.

Comment: is it related to something like http request header?

Comment: @Steven Cookies are sent to the browser in the response. `$_COOKIE` is set from the request. That's why it takes 2 steps.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are sent as part of your page's HTTP response so they don't exist until *after* your response is sent. That's why you have to reload the page to see the value.