# Cookie are not set untill refresh the web page

Tags: php, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t set PHP cookie on the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455214/cant-set-php-cookie-on-the-same-page)

I have this below code:

```
    <?php
    $value = 'something from somewhere';

    setcookie("TestCookie1", $value);
    setcookie("TestCookie2", $value, time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
    setcookie("TestCookie31", $value, time()+3600);

     echo "<pre>";
     print_r($_COOKIE);
     echo "</pre>";


     ?>
```

When I see above code first time in my browser It print only blank array however it display only when I refresh page next time. How I can display cookie in first time run of web page.
Thanks

Comment: You can't. That's how cookies work. What you *can* do is set a number of default values if the cookie does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly, that's how it works. It's even mentioned in the manual. `$_COOKIE` contains the cookies *of this request*, not any cookies you are going to send back to the client in the response.

Since you're just setting the values, you should know what they are, so there's nothing really you can't do given this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

set cookie will add the cookies to the response so the client/browser knows the at the moment the page is shown. $COOKIES gets its cookies from the request. It only contains the cookies the browser/client already has.