# Cookie Worked Correctly Once, but Now Isn't Set

Tags: php, cookies

**Edit**

Okay, so currently my search page is

```
<?php

 ...
        while($row = $search->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
           $result .= "Title: " . $row['comicTitle'];
           $result .= " Issue: " . $row['comicIssue'];
           $result .= " Release: " . $row['releaseDate']."<BR>";

        }
         setcookie('results', $result);

    }

    ?>


    <!doctype html>
    <html>
```

and my results page is:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_COOKIE['results'])) {
        echo $_COOKIE['results'];
        }else{
        echo "There are no results to display.";    

}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
```

The results show correctly the first time, but if I go to the search page and search again I get the previous results. Is the echo in my if(isset) statement causing that or something else?

---

**Original Post**

I have a variable, $results, that I'm trying to save to a cookie so it can be displayed on a results page.

On the search page, to set the cookie, I use this: 
`setcookie ('resultcookie', $result, time()+300);`

On the results page, I use this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['resultcookie'])) {
        echo $_COOKIE['resultcookie'];
        setcookie('resultcookie', "", time()-86400);
    }else{
        echo "There are no results to display.";
```

The first time I tried using the page, the results showed up correctly. Now, when I try to search I always get the "There are no results to display." I've tried not unsetting the cookie, so it would write over it but it didn't seem to work. I tried unsetting it with $result in place of "", but that also didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't find a bug, can you share the more parts of your code?

Comment: The rest of the code is just the query and what not. I can post it, but I'm not sure it'd help. It's almost as if the cookie is just slow to respond. I can get results for a search, but then when I try a new search it returns the results for the first search. If I try to unset the cookie, it won't let me reset it for a while.

Comment: cookies are set in http headers.. It's hard to tell from your code.. but If the cookie is getting written when the results page is loaded... - it wouldn't be read by the results page until the next time you load the page.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707721/are-newly-created-cookies-not-available-until-a-subsequent-page-load

Comment: Wait, just to clarify, the cookie is written with the setcookie. Since I have the setcookie within `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")`, does that mean it's being written on the page with the form, or the page that form posts to?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set a cookie after an echo.  It is the same as any other http header.
I don't see all of your code, but here

```
 echo $_COOKIE['resultcookie'];
 setcookie('resultcookie', "", time()-86400);
```

you don't delete the cookie.  This setcookie() fails for sure.  Use setcookie() before you output anything from your script, and it will be fixed.

Comment: Is unsetting the cookie a necessary step? If I remove the results page setcookie(), when I go back to the search page and put in different search terms, will the search page setcookie() just overwrite the previous cookie?

Comment: Yes, it will overwrite the previous value. Delete is not necessary. The value you set however, will be available after the next page load to the browser.